# Timer Error in Unity

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

Hi everyone Im running into an Error. Im trying to make a timer to spawn an Enemy, once you hit a trigger. The timer counts down, but I run into this error

Control cannot fall through from one case label 'case "EnemyTrigger"' to another.

Here is the code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour {

 public GameObject Enemy;
 public float mytimer = 5.0f;

 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
     switch(other.gameObject.name)
     {
         case "EnemyTrigger":

             if(mytimer > 0){
                 mytimer -=Time.deltaTime;
                 }
             else 
             if(mytimer<=0){

                 Destroy(other.gameObject);

                 Transform enemy;
                 GameObject enemySpawnPoint = GameObject.Find("EnemySpawn");

                 enemy =      Instantiate(Enemy,enemySpawnPoint.transform.position,enemySpawnPoint.transform.rotation) as Transform; 
                 Debug.Log("Spawned Enemy");
                 break;
                 }
         }
     }
}
```

Can anybody explain to me what the error is saying? And also what should I do to change it?

Comment: The 'break' is inside the if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution

```
switch(other.gameObject.name)
{
    case "EnemyTrigger":

        if(mytimer > 0)
            mytimer -=Time.deltaTime;

        else if(mytimer<=0)
        {   
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

            Transform enemy;
            GameObject enemySpawnPoint = GameObject.Find("EnemySpawn");

            enemy = Instantiate(Enemy,enemySpawnPoint.transform.position,
                        enemySpawnPoint.transform.rotation) as Transform; 
            Debug.Log("Spawned Enemy");

        }

    break;
}
```

You were getting the error because you had the corresponding `break` for your `case` buried inside a `else-if` statement.

Comment: Thanks I see now, but now my timer isn't counting down. Well kinda. It countdown and freezes everytime you step into the trigger. It doesnt countdown automatically for 5-0 by it self. How can I fix this?

Comment: You would need to edit or create a new question and explain what you are trying to do. I have no clue.